# How to handle gridview contentY , Y position from parent Flickable in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have a backGroundList and on top gridview in a Flickable.

I want handle gridview contentY , Y position from parent Flickable, it is working when i assign gridview height as content height but due to memory issues i dont want create items before.

Code:

```
Flickable {
            id: mainFlickable
            width: 1920
            height: 1080
            contentHeight: gridView.contentHeight + 660 + 140 // topmargin + bottom margin

            ListView {
                id:backGroundList
                width: 1920
                height: 1080
                y: mainFlickable.contentY
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal

                MouseArea {
                    id: myMA12
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                }
            }

            GridView {
                id: gridView
                objectName: "gridView"

                width: 1920
                height: 1080



                cellWidth: 372
                cellHeight: 290

                interactive: false
                 y: {
                    if (mainFlickable.contentY > 660)
                        return 660 + (mainFlickable.contentY - 660)
                    else
                        return 660
                }

                contentY: {
                    if (mainFlickable.contentY > 660){
                        return (mainFlickable.contentY - 660)
                    }
                    else {
                        return 0
                    }
                }

                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 352
                    height: 270
                    color: "blue"
                    opacity: 0.5

                    Text {
                        text: index
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
                model:100
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left
                    leftMargin: 30
                    right: parent.right
                    rightMargin: 30
                }
            }
}
```

Its not working as expected. **When I update Y value ContentY is updating to zero automatically**

Constraint: Qt5.9.0

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: Can you provide a quick wireframe of how you want your UI to look like? To give us an higher level view of your needs. I feel like you are on the wrong track with nesting 2 `Flickables` into 1 (`ListView` and `GridView` both inherit from `Flickable`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to have two `...View`s one ontop of the other. When one of them has flicked to the end, you want to have that `View` flicked out of the Window, with the second one apprearing and start flicking through this.

In my opinion this is not cleanly achivable with one `Flickable` nesting the other two.

It is easily achived by using a `Flickable` that is a sibling to them. In my example code I use two Flickables. One for the control of the `contentY`-properties, and one that is responsible for scrolling inbetween the two `View`s. Latter could be easily and more efficiently solved by just using an `Item` instead.

```
Window {
    id: rootWin
    width: 800; height: 600; visible: true

    Flickable {
        id: flck
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: lv1.height + lv2.height
        interactive: false
        contentY: Math.min(Math.max(0, mainFlick.contentY - lv1.contentHeight + lv1.height), contentHeight - height)

        ListView {
            id: lv1
            height: rootWin.height
            width: 100
            model: 90
            delegate: Rectangle {
                border.width: 1
                width: 100
                height: 50
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: index
                }
            }
            interactive: false
            contentY: Math.min(mainFlick.contentY, contentHeight - height)
            onContentYChanged: console.log(contentY, contentHeight, height)
        }
        ListView {
            id: lv2
            height: rootWin.height
            anchors.top: lv1.bottom
            width: 100
            model: 90
            delegate: Rectangle {
                border.width: 1
                width: 100
                height: 50
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: index
                }
            }
            interactive: false
            contentY: Math.min(Math.max(0, mainFlick.contentY - lv1.contentHeight), contentHeight - height)
        }
    }
    Flickable {
        id: mainFlick
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: lv1.contentHeight + lv2.contentHeight
    }
}
```